# HashMap into DefaultListModel

Tags: java, hashmap, defaultlistmodel

Here's the code that I have:

```
HashMap<String, String> inst1 = new HashMap(instructorIO.getInstructors());
instListModel = new DefaultListModel<String>(inst1.values());
```

I get errors:

```
DepartmentProject.java:69: error: constructor DefaultListModel in class DefaultListModel<E> cannot be applied to given types;
    required: no arguments
    found: Collection<String>
    reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
    where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class DefaultListModel
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: `DefaultListModel` doesn't take any parameters and you are passing it a collection.

Comment: is there a way to put each values from hashmap into the list model?

Comment: You need to add elements to the `ListModel`, so loop through your `HashMap` and add each value to the `ListModel`

Comment: when i do a loop to (a.getValue()) and trys to add them in i get
DepartmentProject.java:72: error: method addElement in class DefaultListModel<E> cannot be applied to given types;
actual argument Object cannot be converted to String by method invocation conversion
  where E is a type-variable:

Comment: i got to it work, i changed it to (a.getValue() + " "); and somehow it passed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DefaultListModel` only has a constructor that takes no arguments; you can't pass the values you want as a constructor arg.
You will have to create the DefaultListModel and then populate it afterward, for example:

```
HashMap<String, String> inst1 = new HashMap(instructorIO.getInstructors());
instListModel = new DefaultListModel<String>();
for (String value : inst1.values())
{
    instListModel.addElement(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HashMap<Integer, Employee> employees = new HashMap<>();

DefaultListModel<Employee> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
model.addAll(employees.values());
```